# How can I control log messages for Apache (specifically, auth_mysql module & WSGI)?

Tags: logging, wsgi, apache-2.2, mod-auth-mysql

On an Ubuntu 10.04 server w/ Apache2, I have auth_mysql turned on, and I am getting [debug] messages showing up.  How can I turn these off?  I'm guessing there is a way to turn this off for the module, as well as for all 'debug' messages.  I am curious how to do both.

**Update:**
Originally I posted about auth-mysql only; however, I also want to control WSGI's output (currently showing [info] messages in error.log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in /etc/apache/apache2.conf, set `LogLevel` to warn or error

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel

to control logging on a module level do this:

`LogLevel error mod_wsgi:warn` (global log level to error, but show warnings from the wsgi module)

I believe this ability was added in apache 2.4...

Comment: Any idea on how to control this on a individual module level?

Comment: updated answer to include details about module level logging

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `wsgi:warn`, not `mod_wsgi:warn`.